# How to call another method only after first method is completly done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I have a situation where I need to use array in a method, which is previously populated in first method.

I need both methods to execute on `componentDidMount`, for example load countries, after that load towns for current country in droopdown. It goes something like that.

Lets say I need to call this 2 methods separately:

```
async componentDidMount() {
      this.loadCountries();
      this.loadCities(this.state.currentCountry.id);
}
```

How can I be sure first method is done with executing because I need to use countries array `countries[],` in my second method.

Right now I have situation data is retrieved from a server but second method is not aware of it becasue data are retrieved asynhronous probably, and that's it..

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: use `await` before function call, i.e `await this.loadCountires()`

Comment: @CodeManiac Could you post full example please :)

Comment: @CodeManiac could u post it as answer so I might accep it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `async/await` method to call second function only after first function get complete .

here is your snippet .

```
var countries = [];
    async componentDidMount() {
         await this.countries = this.loadCountries(); // you will have countries values in 'this.countries'. Which you can access it further . 
         await this.loadCities(this.state.currentCountry.id);
    }
```

Comment: `await this.countries = this.loadCountries();` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

if whatever you return in first method is Global list of coutries[], then the second method would know that